# Baby Rudin Chapter 6, Problem 15 : Strict inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, stieltjes-integral

Problem 15 in Chapter 6 of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin:

> Suppose $f$ is real, continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, $f(a)=f(b)=0$, and $\int_a^b f^2(x)dx = 1$. Prove that
>
> - $\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x)dx = -1/2$
> - $\int_a^b [f'(x)]^2dx \cdot \int_a^b x^2f^2(x)dx > 1/4$

I am able to prove the first part using integration by parts and the second using Cauchy-Schwarz.

To get a strict inequality, I assumed that there was equality, in which case $xf(x) = \lambda f'(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ for some constant $\lambda$. I am unable to get a contradiction with this (note that Rudin has not introduced the exponential and logarithmic functions and so I don't want to integrate both sides directly).

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\lambda \neq 0$. Note that $f$ is solution to the (linear) Cauchy problem $f’(x)=\lambda^{-1}xf(x)$ with the initial condition $f(a)=0$.

So by uniqueness of the solutions of linear first-order ODEs $f=0$.

Comment: Rudin does not go into differential equations. Is there some simpler argument that is tailored for this problem. For example, something using the mean value theorem maybe.

Comment: Then you can just mimic the proof of the uniqueness for solutions of first-order linear ODE: let $M_1$ be the sup norm of $f$ over $[a,b]$, $M_2$ be the max of $|a|$ and $|b|$, and show by induction over $n$ that $|f(t)| \leq n!^{-1}M_1M_2(t-a)^n$...

Comment: Is there some easy argument using some basic theorems? I don't think Rudin expects us to do this.